# Replacing values in app.config with bamboo variables using Bamboo

Tags: variables, bamboo

I am building and preparing deployable artifact on Bamboo. I would like to inject automatically variables that are set in bamboo into application config.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "EMAIL_QUEUE_DEV": "${bamboo.some.variable1}",
    "EmailFrom_DEV": "${bamboo.some.variable2}"
    }
}
```

I expect ${bamboo.some.variable1} and ${bamboo.some.variable2} to be replaced with equivalent bamboo variables values.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've handled this is to use a script or command to run an executable that can handle find and replace on the file.  To do this you will need to set some sort of placeholder text to key off of:

For windows you could use [regexreplace](https://sites.google.com/site/regexreplace/). Example:

```
C:\Web.Config\rxrepl.exe ${bamboo.workingDirectory}/app.config -a --no-backup -s "email_queue_palceholder" -r "${bamboo.some.variable1}"
```

For cross-platform support you could use a [perl](https://www.perl.org/) script from within Bamboo.  To do this set the perl executable as an executable command in Bamboo, and then for the task type select command.  The script would look something like this:

```
-p "-i.bak" -e "s/\"EMAIL_QUEUE_DEV\": \"e_mail_queue_placeholder\"}\"\,/\"EMAIL_QUEUE_DEV\": \"${bamboo.some.variable1}\"/g" app.config
```

Comment: I was also thinking about that, but the problem with that solution is - if I add new variable, then I need to modify script for substitution as well. I do not want that. Instead I want to iterate over all bamboo variables and if equivalent is found in file - replace it with variable value.

Comment: If you have several variables you want to iterate over you will need a script.  It can be inline or a file, shell/powershell or a scripting language like Python. You'll need to 1) query all of the bamboo plan variables (env | grep bamboo_), 2) Look to see if you have a placeholder variable that matches the variable name, and 3) run some sort of find/replace command like the ones above.

Comment: @user1696503 in addition to Wesley Rolnick answer and comment: all variables in Bamboo are also available as environment variable, and the `env | grep bamboo_` will print all of them (also available in the logs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solution like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294840/142850) or [this other one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294837/142850) and change your `app.config` file to use the environment variables instead:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "EMAIL_QUEUE_DEV": "${bamboo_some_variable1}",
    "EmailFrom_DEV": "${bamboo_some_variable2}"
    }
}
```

Here we do not use the Bamboo variable in the form `${bamboo.some.variable1}` (as their substitution happens only when Bamboo sees the script) but their equivalent environment variable `${bamboo_some_variable1}`. Those are automatically declared by Bamboo.